# Create switch based on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a normal javascript switch that'll give me an alert message and image based on what the user has selected from a drop down menu

here's what I have so far

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>How are you feeling?</h1>
<img id="feelimg" src="Images/questionSun.jpg" alt="question sun">
<select id="feeling" onChange="changeFeeling();">
  <option value="question">Question</option>
  <option value="happy">Happy</option>
  <option value="sad">Sad</option>
  <option value="cool">Cool</option>
  <option value="unsure">Unsure</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var curFeel = document.getElementById('feeling').value;

  function changeFeeling(){
      switch (curFeel) {
        case 'question':  {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/questionSun.jpg";
          alert("Please make a selection or go back to bed!");
          break;
        }
        case 'happy': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/happySun.jpg";
          alert("I am glad you are happy");
          return curFeel;
          break;
        }
        case 'sad': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/sadSun.jpg";
          alert("I am sorry you are sad");
          break;
        }
        case 'cool': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/coolSun.jpg";
          alert("It's great you are feeling cool!");
          break;
        }
        case 'unsure': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/unsureSun.jpg";
          alert("I hope you get past that soon!");
          break;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I do it is stuck on case question. It needs to be javascript. I am not allowed to use jquery for this particular problem.

Comment: Hi Nalani, you should accept one of the answears that helped you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your switch variable `event.target.value` and it will work how you want it to.

To access a global `var` from inside a function

```
var curFeel;

function changeFeeling(){

    curFeel = event.target.value;

    switch (curFeel) {
        case 'question':  {
      ....

        }
    }
}
```

That way the variable `curFeel` will be whatever the selected value is globally.
[Heres a Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPePPw)

Comment: Not sure exactly how to do that. Very new to java-script. Started learning it 5 weeks ago.

Comment: When an event like onChange fires it passes through an `event` object to the connected function. The `event` object allows you amongst other things to access the `target` in the same way `document.getElementById` does. If you experiment you will find that it is always available when connected to an event listener like onChange or onClick.

Comment: Okay so how would that look for example

Answer (score 1):

Just move your var declaration inside your function.

The way you have done the var was getting populated with the value once the javascript gets loaded, moving it to the function it will be populated at the onChange event and then the switch works nice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var curFeel = document.getElementById('feeling').value;    

  function changeFeeling(){

      curFeel = document.getElementById('feeling').value;

      switch (curFeel) {
        case 'question':  {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/questionSun.jpg";
          alert("Please make a selection or go back to bed!");
          break;
        }
        case 'happy': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/happySun.jpg";
          alert("I am glad you are happy");
          return curFeel;
          break;
        }
        case 'sad': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/sadSun.jpg";
          alert("I am sorry you are sad");
          break;
        }
        case 'cool': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/coolSun.jpg";
          alert("It's great you are feeling cool!");
          break;
        }
        case 'unsure': {
          document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/unsureSun.jpg";
          alert("I hope you get past that soon!");
          break;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Another way that I would recomend is to not use this global variable and just use the parameter using the onchange like that:

```
<select id="feeling" onChange="changeFeeling(this);">
  <option value="question">Question</option>
  <option value="happy">Happy</option>
  <option value="sad">Sad</option>
  <option value="cool">Cool</option>
  <option value="unsure">Unsure</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">



      function changeFeeling(curFeel){          


          switch (curFeel.value) {
            case 'question':  {
              document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/questionSun.jpg";
              alert("Please make a selection or go back to bed!");
              break;
            }
            case 'happy': {
              document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/happySun.jpg";
              alert("I am glad you are happy");
              return curFeel;
              break;
            }
            case 'sad': {
              document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/sadSun.jpg";
              alert("I am sorry you are sad");
              break;
            }
            case 'cool': {
              document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/coolSun.jpg";
              alert("It's great you are feeling cool!");
              break;
            }
            case 'unsure': {
              document.getElementById("feelimg").src = "Images/unsureSun.jpg";
              alert("I hope you get past that soon!");
              break;
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: But if the variable is in the function it's no longer global that's my issue I need to use a global variable

Comment: For what reason Nalani, can you explain more so I can help you with that ?

Comment: It's the parameters I was giving for this problem. They stated I needed to Outside the function
Declare a global variable to store the selection made from the selection box

Comment: I you really whant it to be global move it again to where it was and re assign the value on change to the variable.

Comment: @NalaniRowe I've just updated my answear and added another way to pass it using parameter. take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Diego Garcia has provided the answer, but I'd like to suggest a simple improvement to the code generally for you to collect a few bonus points (should they be available).

```
var curFeel; // Value is not being used before changeFeeling function call, so you only need declare it rather than assign a value

function changeFeeling(){

  var picture, message; // Declare variables to contain the decided upon image and alert message
  var pictureFiles = 'Images/'; // Where your image files are kept, so you don't repeat a dozen times below

  curFeel = document.getElementById('feeling').value;

  switch (curFeel) {
    case 'question':  {
      picture = "questionSun.jpg";
      message = "Please make a selection or go back to bed!";
      break;
    }
    case 'happy': {
      picture = "happySun.jpg";
      message = "I am glad you are happy";
      break;
    }
    case 'sad': {
      picture = "sadSun.jpg";
      message = "I am sorry you are sad";
      break;
    }
    case 'cool': {
      picture = "coolSun.jpg";
      message = "It's great you are feeling cool!";
      break;
    }
    case 'unsure': {
      picture = "unsureSun.jpg";
      message = "I hope you get past that soon!";
      break;
    }
  }

  // Set image and alert message!
  document.getElementById("feelimg").src(pictureFiles + picture);
  alert(message);
}
```

Reasons Why:

- The above is easier to read
- In the event that the ID of the picture element, or the location of the image files, changes you only need to change it in one place rather than a dozen
- And the same if the behaviour around the message alert changes, e.g. instead of using the alert() function, the message is inserted into a div element on the page instead for example (only one change required rather than a dozen)

Hope this helps.